# How can I change starting directory in MinGW?

Tags: mingw

I found my MinGW changed its starting directory so I should do some stuff to go back to original home directory.
I want to change its starting directory!

Answer (score 0):

Move it on the disk and reconfigure the environment variable `MINGW_HOME`